# This was the first time I'd been abroad or this was the first time I was abroad?

Tags: past-perfect

I was reading the following article https://www.theguardian.com/travel/2003/jan/26/naples.italy.observerescapesection

and encountered some usages of the Past Perfect that I didn't quite get why they were used in the way they were used.

For example, the writer says: "I was 14, and this was the first time I'd been abroad". She clearly talks here about the same stretch of time so to say - her first time being abroad. So why is it divided to two actions by using the Past Perfect? shouldn't it be - It was my first time being abroad/It was the first time that I was abroad?

The same goes for this citation: "It was my first, and the most unflattering thing I'd ever seen in my life" - why does she use both tenses for a single event?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "The first time" is used with perfect tenses, present or past.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is *duration*, i.e. she narrates something taking place *during* that trip, then past perfect is perfectly correct, and the common way to express it.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Do you mean that it's like a reported speech when the narrating is done in the present and therefore whatever past event is narrated, it's done by using the Past Perfect?

Comment: But it still doesn't make sense if that is the case - we use the Past Perfect in reported speech only when we describe something that in the original event was also in the past. e.g.- (in the next comment because I don't have enough characters left for this box)

Comment: E.g.- "He said he had been there the previous day" is rephrasing someone who said "I was there yesterday", meaning, that speaker already narrated his story by using the past. Whereas if that speaker is saying "I'm here today for the first time", we'd phrase it to "He said it was his first time there". So why would the abovementioned writer say "it was the first time I'd been abroad" if rephrasing it to the "original state", as if it reported speech, would be "It is the first time I was abroad"  while it's supposed to be phrased "it's the first time that I'm abroad".